# A bash script that receives any integer numbers and print their mean with 2 decimal digit accuracy

Tags: bash, for-loop, mean, declare

I need to write a bash script that receives any integer numbers and print their mean with 2 decimal digit accuracy
I used the following code but it did not work

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i sum=0
read -p "Enter n: " n
numberCount=$((n | wc -c))
for sum=$((n>=0; n<=0; n++));do echo "scale=2; $sum/$numberCount" | bc;done
```

Comment: Edit your question and add example input and your desired output (no description) for that sample input.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but this is not a question. Please read [ask]. If you're looking for a full solution, there are existing questions that should be usable, like [Scripts for computing the average of a list of numbers in a data file](/q/15681498/4518341); the awk solution looks good, and you would just need to figure out how to round in awk.

Comment: decompose your compound statements and make sure they are working as you expect. I think you find that `n=3; n| wc -c` (or `$n | wc -c`) isn't doing what you need. There may be others. Good luck.

Comment: Have a look at GNU `datamash`.

Comment: `declare -i sum=0 count=0; while read -r -p 'Enter n: ' n; do [[ -z ${n#-} || ${n#-} == *[^[:digit:]]* ]] && break; sum+=n; count+=1; done; (( count == 0 )) && exit 0; printf '%.2f\n' "$((100 * sum/count))e-2"`

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use awk:

```
#!/bin/bash
function divide() {
    awk 'BEGIN{printf("%.2f\n", '$1'/'$2')}'
}
divide 1 2
divide 10 2
divide 10 3
# Output
# 0.50
# 5.00
# 3.33
```

If you want to input the values interactively then:

```
function divide() {
    read -p "First number: " n1
    read -p "Second number: " n2
    awk 'BEGIN{printf("%.2f\n", '$n1'/'$n2')}'
}
divide
```

Answer (score 1):

or make a more generic version that allows customization of output precision :

```
echo '1 2
      10 2
      10 3' |
```

> ```
> awk '($++NF = sprintf("%.*f", __, $++_ / $(_+_)))^--_' __='13'
> ```

```
1 2 0.5000000000000
10 2 5.0000000000000
10 3 3.3333333333333
```